# How to hide the div where the button is in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to hide the div where a button is located in.

I have allot of php generated divs with a button remove.
And when i click on remove the div where the button is located inside the whole div should be hidden.

This is some code to clarify a little bit.

```
       $('#button').click(function(){
          $("The Parent Div Of This Button").hide();
       });
```

I tried to find online how to hide "The Parent Div Of This Button" but i cannot seem to find id and i'm pretty sure it's super easy..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try more search strings next time, for example **jquery hide parent** or **jquery hide parent element**, or even **jquery  parent of this** and then apply the hide bit yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).parent().hide();` or `$(this).closest('div').hide();` if there are another elements between 'parent' and button (eg. div > span > button).

Comment: This worked when i named the div with an "id" but then it would only hide one div and the rest would not be able to be hidden. And when i use "class" it doesnt work at all. any ideas?

Comment: Hmm it only removes the first php generated div. >.>

Comment: What class? What id? You spoke first time about parent and div (no class, no id). What code we spoke about now exactly?

Comment: The class of the parent div, So there a multiple php generated div's with a class and if i try to hide any div by clicking on the button, it only works for the first generated div. With the rest of the php generated div's it wont work

Comment: add fiddle link. If you use `$(this).closest('div.classname').hide();`, you have to hide the parent div.classname, nothing else. this is button you've clicked on.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `event` parameter to access, and hide, the `parent` element

```
$('#button').click(function(event){
      $(event.target).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: @GôTô because there's absolutely no need

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function(){   
 $(this).closest('div').hide(); 
});
```